# How can I find out the supported parameters in the query string for a URL?

Tags: c#, url

Is there a way that I can know what parameters are been implemented in the query string of one certain URL? For example, with the http://esri.com/rest/services/myself/?f=JSON, how can I know it can have this f=json parameter in the query string if I only have http://esri.com/rest/services/myself/ URL?

Thanks for your help!

Wei

Comment: do you have list of variables that you are expecting from that url? if so, you can check whether the variable is appended in the url or not.

Comment: Since this is an esri question perhaps you should try on the gis site too.

Comment: It seems that you know the company and the GIS field, Doug. I will post the question on their forum. Thanks for you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could know is if the site owner tells you.

If you're working with a REST API, its documentation should include this information. If you're just going after some URL on the Internet, there's probably no way for you to know.

Comment: virtual -1. REST API does not need documentation, it uses `link` to document itself.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean "uses link to document itself". Could you explain it a little bit more in detail? Thanks,

Comment: @Aliostad, in this case the querystring says which representation to return. `link` would most likely just tell you about other data within the same representation.

Comment: Calling REST "self-documenting" is a simple matter of redefining the term "self-documenting".

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do this.

Consider that the acceptable parameters may depend on the other parameters provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code, you will look at what is used otherwise, you cannot do other than a wild guess.